Arab media reaction to Iranian attack
What has been Arab media reaction to Iran violating the air space of several Arab-Muslim countries (notably Iraq and Jordan, which are not Iranian client states) during their drone and missile attacks on Israel on April 14th 2024?

@thegodsfromengineering We generally don't do press roundups here. - is there a meta thread which outlines this policy?

@RogerV.: no, but Q about what the press said were sometimes closed. And sometimes weren't. But IIRC [those that weren't] generally they were of the 'why' variety, which are more ambiguous. Often the claimant/asker implied the press is politically biased [all in one direction], which is certainly the case in some parts of the world.

https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6876/are-press-roundups-on-topic

I had missed the other rather recent Q on Arab media that made HNQ. And where you wrote an answer. I guess consensus can change. Anyhow, best debated on meta, where I started a discussion.

I have deleted several comments picking out individual news sources. As this question is specifically asking for media reactions, these should be (parts of) answers, not comments. Please don't use comments for partial answers. If you want to answer, post a proper answer.

@Philipp, This is my last comment here. Based on my previous experience in this website, I'm quite sure that if I posted a very similar question to this one but about potential wrong-doings of Israel, moderators like you would close it immediately.

@apadana I rewrote a part of the question to make it more neutral. Note that making edits to questions is not a moderator prerogative. When a question fails to uphold the neutrality standards this community should have, then anyone can propose edits and any users with 1000 reputation can make edits directly. See https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit
